# openstack autopilot deployed new machine with juju not showing in horizon dashboard

Tags: juju, maas, openstack-autopilot

I added new machine in MAAS and deployed it in juju by using the following command:

```
mrau1@mrau1$ juju ssh landscape-server/0 sudo 'JUJU_HOME=/var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/`sudo ls -rt /var/lib/landscape/juju-
-homes/ | tail -1` sudo -u landscape -E bash'

landscape@juju-machine-0-lxc-1:~$ juju add-unit --to node5.maas nova-compute
```

When I check, it added the new machine:

```
$ juju status
"7":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.25.4
    dns-name: node5.maas
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-57xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=16 mem=xxx36M

nova-compute/6:
        workload-status:
          current: active
          message: Unit is ready
          since: 19 May 2016 23:26:52Z
        agent-status:
          current: idle
          since: 19 May 2016 23:26:54Z
          version: 1.25.4
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.25.4
        machine: "7"
        public-address: node5.maas
        subordinates:
          ceilometer-agent/5:
            workload-status:
              current: active
              message: Unit is ready
              since: 19 May 2016 23:08:39Z
            agent-status:
              current: idle
              since: 19 May 2016 23:23:42Z
              version: 1.25.4
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.25.4
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/ceilometer-agent-12
            public-address: node5.maas
          landscape-client/21:
            workload-status:
              current: unknown
              since: 19 May 2016 23:09:02Z
            agent-status:
              current: idle
              since: 19 May 2016 23:25:15Z
              version: 1.25.4
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.25.4
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/landscape-client-12
            public-address: node5.maas
          neutron-openvswitch/5:
            workload-status:
              current: active
              message: Unit is ready
              since: 19 May 2016 23:07:18Z
            agent-status:
              current: idle
              since: 19 May 2016 23:27:21Z
              version: 1.25.4
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.25.4
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/neutron-openvswitch-12
            public-address: node5.maas
          ntp/6:
            workload-status:
              current: unknown
              since: 19 May 2016 23:03:07Z
            agent-status:
              current: idle
              since: 19 May 2016 23:26:55Z
              version: 1.25.4
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.25.4
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/ntp-12
            public-address: node5.maas
```

But the problem is, it is not showing in openstack horizon dashboard.

I would like to use new host. How I can do that?